# Multiple glyphicons in one element using :before and :after

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am trying to use the default Bootstrap icons called Glyphicons to style one `span` with three overlapping icons, which will open many new possibilities in the sparse library of Bootstrap icons.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfh68qv8/) is where I am at the moment, but I would love to use three icons in one html element, instead of just two, and I would rather not use images or sprites but utilize the already existing glyphicons.

Oh, and I am also trying to make the code CSS 2.1 for browser compatibility.

It seems to me that the following CSS part doesn't work, the content icon is only set when I use `:before` and `:after`

```
.glyphicon-picture {
    content: "\e060";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How would you modify this code to get three overlapping icons(trying to make a typical carousel icon, with one big in the middle, and two small partly behind on each side)?

Comment: The `content` property only works on :before and :after , not the element itself.

Comment: @JonSnow: Thanks, I did not know this. @Paulie_D: Thanks for the link, I have been thinking about FA, and stacking icons might be easier there, instead of with Bootstrap. But as far as I could gather, I would still have to use 2 html elements (2x`span` or 2x`i`) for what I am currently only using 1 html element for. So I wouldn't exactly call it a duplicate.